# Can't hear over Bluetooth headset

Tags: sound, ubuntu-touch, bluetooth

On my ubuntu phone when connected to Bluetooth headset or "hands free" in the car at the time of the call I can't hear the caller and he cannot hear me (The device successfully mated). I tried to choose different options for the proposed source playback: Speaker phone, Bluetooth Headset, phone. Everything works, except the Bluetooth Headset.

How do I determine what is it?

bq aquarius e4.5 ubuntu edition

Comment: Same here with BQ Aquaris E5 Ubuntu Edition